# Python while statement turtle.distance

Tags: python, distance, turtle-graphics

It is my understanding that the following code

```
turtle.forward(50)
```

means moving the turtle on the screen.

Here is a code I am trying to learn:

```
def forward(distance):
while distance > 0:
    if turtle.distance(0,0) > 100:
        angle = turtle.towards(0,0)
        turtle.setheading(angle)
    turtle.forward(1)
    distance = distance - 1
```

I don't really understand how

```
turtle.forward(1)
distance = distance -1
```

works here. I understand that if the distance is greater than 100, then the turtle turns back and moves from the end position to the position less than 100. I experimented with it but it is still not clear to me what the code turtle.forward(1) means. Is the turtle supposed to move by 1 pixel? And the final distance is less by another pixel? When I put in different numbers instead of 1, I get strange results. Sorry for asking this question - I am learning very slowly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`turtle.forward(1)` is telling the turtle to move forward in the current direction by one pixel.

`if turtle.distance(0,0) > 100` checks how far away the turtle is from the origin (center of the pane) and see if it's greater than 100.

`angle = turtle.towards(0,0) turtle.setheading(angle)` turns the turtle towards the origin

Here's how it comes together:

```
def forward(distance):
    while distance > 0: # loop this while there's still distance 
        if turtle.distance(0,0) > 100: # check if the distance from the origin is greater that 100
            angle = turtle.towards(0,0) # find the angle for the origin from turtle's current location 
            turtle.setheading(angle) # turns the turtle toward the angle
        turtle.forward(1) # move title forward in the current angle by one pixel 
        distance = distance - 1 # act as a counter for the while loop, so when distance is finally 0, the while loop breaks
```

Comment: Thanks @abccd. I understand how the code works up to the last line: 
distance = distance -1

Comment: I've just noticed that part of my comment got cut off. What I meant to say that I could not understand the logic of the last line. So if I put number 110 for distance, the turtle will end up at point 92. I just could not understand why the final distance is  distance - 1. I am trying to find other options for this as EyuelDK says.

Comment: As I said, `distance = distance = 1`is a counter, the whole loop is exactly the same as `for _ in range(distance):`. The turtle will continue moving until the counter finishes. Which means it will move back and forth until the loop stops, one pixel at time.

Comment: Thanks @abccd. I used the `for _ in range(distance)` which does make sense to me. There is no need for additional `line distance = distance - step` there. So I am not sure if the while loop is a good choice here.

Comment: I would prefer the latter option with the for loop. Unless you wanted to use/changed `distance` but I don't think it's necessary. Both are fine..

Comment: Thank you @abccd for your patience. I now finally understand how the while loop works in this particular case - the counter `distance = distance -1`. It counts the steps backwards whereas the for loop counts from the beginning. I only found out because I printed each step and used the `turtle.xcor()` function. It is not easy for me to spot immediately how something works - in this case why it should count backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The code is kind of contradictory to what it tries to achieve. It looks like the `forward` function is trying to move towards position `(0, 0)` in `distance` number of steps.

```
def forward(distance):

    while distance > 0:               

        # if the turtle is more than 100 distance away from (0, 0)
        # change orientation to face (0, 0)               
        if turtle.distance(0,0) > 100:
            angle = turtle.towards(0,0)
            turtle.setheading(angle)

        # Make the turtle move one step towards (0, 0)
        turtle.forward(1)

        # IMO, distance should've been called steps_left 
        distance = distance - 1
```

***LOGICAL INCONSISTENCY***

The code seems like it is trying to make the turtle move towards the origin `(0, 0)` **BUT** at the same time it has a counter of sorts called `distance` - that acts more like `steps_allowed_to_take` - which might cause the turtle to reach the origin but still attempt to move towards the origin. The `turtle.forward(1)` in this scenario would actually cause the turtle to move one step away from the origin and in the next loop, the turtle would move back to the origin. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Many thanks @EyuelDK. I commented on the answer from abccd as well. I am having great difficulty understanding the logic of this code which is given as an exercise. The point of this exercise is to prevent the turtle from going over a set distance. If it goes over number 100, we are supposed to make it stop and go back before number 100, not necessarily all the way to the starting point. Yes, the variable distance is confusing, so I replaced it with steps_left - but it still doesn't make sense to me: why should the last 2 lines of code be turtle.forward(1) andsteps_left = steps_left - 1?

Comment: it doesn't have to be - but it is. In programming, there are many ways to accomplish the same thing, so don't think about it as if it a must but rather an option. After your clarification, i.e. telling me the original purpose, I understand the code a little bit more. You can think of the program as if it is trying to move the turtle inside a 100 radius circle who's center is at `(0, 0)` within a set number of steps, i.e. `distance` amount. The last two lines make the turtle advance towards the center of this circle and the `distance = distance - 1` updates the # of steps allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This function is a replacement for `turtle.forward()` that keeps a turtle that's on a random walk within a circular boundary.

Consider a simplified version of the function:

```
def forward(distance):
    while distance > 0:
        turtle.forward(1)
        distance = distance - 1
```

It does exactly what `turtle.forward(distance)` does, though less efficiently.  It moves the turtle forward one pixel at a time until it goes the entire distance, rather then go the whole distance in one motion via `turtle.forward(distance)`.  Why?  This allows the code to make a decision on each pixel of the move regarding whether the turtle has violated the boundary and adjust its heading:

```
    if turtle.distance(0, 0) > 100:
        angle = turtle.towards(0, 0)
        turtle.setheading(angle)
```

Let's embed this function in code to illustrate what it does:

```
from random import randint
import turtle

def forward(distance):
    while distance > 0:
        if turtle.distance(0, 0) > 100:
            angle = turtle.towards(0, 0)
            turtle.setheading(angle)
        turtle.forward(1)
        distance = distance - 1

boundary = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
boundary.color("red")
boundary.penup()
boundary.sety(-100)
boundary.pendown()
boundary.circle(100)

turtle.shape("turtle")  # default turtle

for _ in range(1000):  # akin to while True:
    turtle.left(randint(0, 90))
    forward(randint(1, 50))

turtle.done()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cdlane. This is interesting and as I commented on abccd answer I understand the code better with `for _ in range` loop in this case.